# Iam unable to create pod using kubernetes.yaml file

Tags: kubernetes

I am using below yaml file. I tried this yaml file by executing the command kubectl apply -f <yaml_file_name>.yaml on mac but I am unable to create pot and load balancer.

```
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Namespace
metadata:
  name: applicare
  labels:
    name: applicare
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
data:
  app.properties: |
    applicare.dbVendor=MySql
    applicare.autoPersist=true
    applicare.useSNMP=0
    applicare.stuckthread.max=600
    applicare.updateUrl=http\://support.arcturustech.com
    applicare.systemUser=JFUuyKJT1Ls\=
    applicare.smtp_auth_pwd=Ni2Bih3nCUU\=
    applicare.useRSTATD=1
    applicare.blackboxSaveType=all
    applicare.invokeRSTATD=1
    applicare.enableChartScrollbar=true
    heapTracker.interval=240
    applicare.serverPort=8880
    applicare.serverSSL=true
    applicare.dbDriverClass=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
    applicare.SMTPSSL=false 
    applicare.adminName=AdminServer
    applicare.dbPassword=Applicare01$1
    applicare.alertDuration=3
    applicare.dbUsername=applicare01
    applicare.smtp_host=localhost
    applicare.dburl=jdbc\:mysql\://192.168.1.209\:3306/applicarenew?allowPublicKeyRetrieval\=true&useSSL\=false
    applicare.smtp_auth_user=test
    applicare.custAlertClass=
    applicare.serverIP=192.168.1.209
    applicare.agentJobInterval=1
    applicare.dbTestSQL=SELECT 1
     applicare.smtp_from=
    applicare.enable_readonly_mode=false
    applicare.sendMailTo=test@localhost.com
    applicare.alertMonitorJobInterval=1
    applicare.alertOn=1
    applicare.intellitrace.auto_refresh=60000
    applicare.SMTPPort=25
    applicare.enable_server_time=false
    applicare.systemPassword=JFUuyKJT1Ls\=
    applicare.serverName=
    applicare.httpErrorCode=400
    applicare.monitorOn=1
    applicare.ipLocUpdate.jobInterval=60
    applicare.alertClearanceNotificationDuration=3
    applicare.logDir=/usr/local/Applicare/logs
    applicare.dataSource=Applicare-DataSource
    applicare.minTimeBetweenAlerts=5
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: applicare-config
  namespace: applicare

---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  namespace: applicare
  labels:
    run: applicare
  name: applicare
spec:
  replicas: 3
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      run: applicare
  template:
    metadata:
      annotations:
      labels:
        run: applicare
spec:
      containers:
      - image: 'applicare:latest'
        imagePullPolicy: Never
        name: applicare
        resources:
          requests:
            memory: "2000Mi"
            cpu: "200m"
          limits:
            memory: "5000Mi"
            cpu: "2000m"
        volumeMounts:
        - name: app-config
          mountPath: /usr/local/Applicare/Applicare.props
          subPath: app.properties
        livenessProbe:
          httpGet:
            path: /applicare/login/console.jsp
            port: 8080
          failureThreshold: 5
          periodSeconds: 60
         #  terminationGracePeriodSeconds: 200
          initialDelaySeconds: 180
        startupProbe:
          httpGet:
            path: /applicare/login/console.jsp
            port: 8080
          failureThreshold: 3
          periodSeconds: 90
      volumes:
      - name: app-config
        configMap:
          name: applicare-config

---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  namespace: applicare
   name: applicare-service
spec:
  selector:
    run: applicare
  ports:
    - port: 443
      targetPort: 8080
      name: port1
    - port: 83
      targetPort: 8983
      name: port2

---

apiVersion: autoscaling/v2
kind: HorizontalPodAutoscaler
metadata:
  name: applicare
  namespace: applicare
spec:
  maxReplicas: 3
  minReplicas: 1
  scaleTargetRef:
    apiVersion: apps/v1
    kind: Deployment
    name: applicare
  metrics:
  - type: Resource
    resource:
      name: cpu
      target:
        type: Utilization
        averageUtilization: 80
  - type: Resource
    resource:
      name: memory
      target:
        type: Utilization
        averageUtilization: 97

---
apiVersion: policy/v1
kind: PodDisruptionBudget
metadata:
  name: applicare-pdb
  namespace: applicare
spec:
  minAvailable: 1
selector:
    matchLabels:
      run: applicare
```

**After execute that yaml file, iam getting below error.**

```
namespace/applicare created
[resource mapping not found for name: "applicare-config" namespace: "applicare" from "Applicare.yaml": no matches for kind "ConfigMap" in version "apps/v1"
ensure CRDs are installed first, error parsing Applicare.yaml: error converting YAML to JSON: yaml: line 5: mapping values are not allowed in this context]
Error from server (BadRequest): error when creating "Applicare.yaml": Deployment in version "v1" cannot be handled as a Deployment: strict decoding error: unknown field "spec.containers", unknown field "spec.volumes"
```

I changed apiversion from apps/v1 to v1, but i got below error. It shows install CRD but I checked kubernetes and crd is there, then I don't know why pod is not created.

```
namespace/applicare unchanged
configmap/applicare-config unchanged
error parsing Applicare.yaml: error converting YAML to JSON: yaml: line 5: mapping values are not allowed in this context
Error from server (BadRequest): error when creating "Applicare.yaml": Deployment in version "v1" cannot be handled as a Deployment: strict decoding error: unknown field "spec.containers", unknown field "spec.volumes"
```

Comment: `I changed apiversion from apps/v1 to v1, ` where did you do that change?

Answer (score 2):

**Configmap** that you are trying to create has to wrong **ApiVersion**

**v1** is the correct version to use

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
```

instead **apiVersion: apps/v1** that is for **deployment** not for **configmap**

Also, **format your indentation properly** first for deployment spec having **space issues**.

Try this file as it is and apply directly

```
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Namespace
metadata:
  name: applicare
  labels:
    name: applicare
---
apiVersion: v1
data:
  app.properties: |
    applicare.dbVendor=MySql
    applicare.autoPersist=true
    applicare.useSNMP=0
    applicare.stuckthread.max=600
    applicare.updateUrl=http\://support.arcturustech.com
    applicare.systemUser=JFUuyKJT1Ls\=
    applicare.smtp_auth_pwd=Ni2Bih3nCUU\=
    applicare.useRSTATD=1
    applicare.blackboxSaveType=all
    applicare.invokeRSTATD=1
    applicare.enableChartScrollbar=true
    heapTracker.interval=240
    applicare.serverPort=8880
    applicare.serverSSL=true
    applicare.dbDriverClass=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
    applicare.SMTPSSL=false 
    applicare.adminName=AdminServer
    applicare.dbPassword=Applicare01$1
    applicare.alertDuration=3
    applicare.dbUsername=applicare01
    applicare.smtp_host=localhost
    applicare.dburl=jdbc\:mysql\://192.168.1.209\:3306/applicarenew?allowPublicKeyRetrieval\=true&useSSL\=false
    applicare.smtp_auth_user=test
    applicare.custAlertClass=
    applicare.serverIP=192.168.1.209
    applicare.agentJobInterval=1
    applicare.dbTestSQL=SELECT 1
     applicare.smtp_from=
    applicare.enable_readonly_mode=false
    applicare.sendMailTo=test@localhost.com
    applicare.alertMonitorJobInterval=1
    applicare.alertOn=1
    applicare.intellitrace.auto_refresh=60000
    applicare.SMTPPort=25
    applicare.enable_server_time=false
    applicare.systemPassword=JFUuyKJT1Ls\=
    applicare.serverName=
    applicare.httpErrorCode=400
    applicare.monitorOn=1
    applicare.ipLocUpdate.jobInterval=60
    applicare.alertClearanceNotificationDuration=3
    applicare.logDir=/usr/local/Applicare/logs
    applicare.dataSource=Applicare-DataSource
    applicare.minTimeBetweenAlerts=5
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: applicare-config
  namespace: applicare

---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  namespace: applicare
  labels:
    run: applicare
  name: applicare
spec:
  replicas: 3
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      run: applicare
  template:
    metadata:
      annotations:
      labels:
        run: applicare
    spec:
      containers:
      - image: 'applicare:latest'
        imagePullPolicy: Never
        name: applicare
        resources:
          requests:
            memory: "2000Mi"
            cpu: "200m"
          limits:
            memory: "5000Mi"
            cpu: "2000m"
        volumeMounts:
        - name: app-config
          mountPath: /usr/local/Applicare/Applicare.props
          subPath: app.properties
        livenessProbe:
          httpGet:
            path: /applicare/login/console.jsp
            port: 8080
          failureThreshold: 5
          periodSeconds: 60
         #  terminationGracePeriodSeconds: 200
          initialDelaySeconds: 180
        startupProbe:
          httpGet:
            path: /applicare/login/console.jsp
            port: 8080
          failureThreshold: 3
          periodSeconds: 90
      volumes:
      - name: app-config
        configMap:
          name: applicare-config

---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  namespace: applicare
  name: applicare-service
spec:
  selector:
    run: applicare
  ports:
    - port: 443
      targetPort: 8080
      name: port1
    - port: 83
      targetPort: 8983
      name: port2

---

apiVersion: autoscaling/v2
kind: HorizontalPodAutoscaler
metadata:
  name: applicare
  namespace: applicare
spec:
  maxReplicas: 3
  minReplicas: 1
  scaleTargetRef:
    apiVersion: apps/v1
    kind: Deployment
    name: applicare
  metrics:
  - type: Resource
    resource:
      name: cpu
      target:
        type: Utilization
        averageUtilization: 80
  - type: Resource
    resource:
      name: memory
      target:
        type: Utilization
        averageUtilization: 97

---
apiVersion: policy/v1
kind: PodDisruptionBudget
metadata:
  name: applicare-pdb
  namespace: applicare
spec:
  minAvailable: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      run: applicare
```

Comment: says `I changed apiversion from apps/v1 to v1, ` in the last line though?

Comment: I already tried sir but i getting below error.



namespace/applicare unchanged
configmap/applicare-config unchanged
error parsing Applicare.yaml: error converting YAML to JSON: yaml: line 5: mapping values are not allowed in this context
Error from server (BadRequest): error when creating "Applicare.yaml": Deployment in version "v1" cannot be handled as a Deployment: strict decoding error: unknown field "spec.containers", unknown field "spec.volumes"

Comment: can you please just copy the file that i have shared and try again i have just updated 5 second back. Copy/paste and apply as it is please.

Comment: great feel free to update the status of question if resolves your issue and mark it as accepted that's how SO works.

Comment: After execute that yaml file, I went to check if the pod is running but I get the below error.


kubectl get pods
Unable to connect to the server: net/http: TLS handshake timeout

Comment: unrelated error and should go in a different question.

Comment: @HarshManvar there's still an annotation without a value in the deployment which is discouraged/"not allowed"

Comment: Right Rick, but k8s will take care of it automatically if no value is specified.

Comment: @anndarc as Rick said feel free to post new questions with proper details as it's an unrelated error. That could due to network, proxy, firewall, client issue.

Comment: May I know what you changed in the yaml file?

Comment: space in spec section of deployment, space in selector of PDB indentation issues, v1 for configmap API version issue.

Comment: if you have any further error feel free to post new question and update the status of this by marking accepted.

Comment: Hi @HarshManvar consider this ticket. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76882406/iam-unable-to-connect-my-pod-application-on-kubernetes?noredirect=1#comment135537220_76882406

Comment: Thanks for sharing David & Rick already helping not jumping middle.

Comment: None of their responses fixed the problem. please consider that.