# Iam unable to connect my pod application on kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes

I have created the pod, namespace and service with below yaml file but I am not able to access the application running in that pod.

```
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Namespace
metadata:
  name: applicare
  labels:
    name: applicare
---
apiVersion: v1
data:
  app.properties: |
    applicare.dbVendor=MySql
    applicare.autoPersist=true
    applicare.useSNMP=0
    applicare.stuckthread.max=600
    applicare.updateUrl=http\://support.arcturustech.com
    applicare.systemUser=JFUuyKJT1Ls\=
    applicare.smtp_auth_pwd=Ni2Bih3nCUU\=
    applicare.useRSTATD=1
    applicare.blackboxSaveType=all
    applicare.invokeRSTATD=1
    applicare.enableChartScrollbar=true
    heapTracker.interval=240
    applicare.serverPort=8880
    applicare.serverSSL=true
    applicare.dbDriverClass=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
    applicare.SMTPSSL=false 
    applicare.adminName=AdminServer
    applicare.dbPassword=Applicare01$1
    applicare.alertDuration=3
    applicare.dbUsername=applicare01
    applicare.smtp_host=localhost
    applicare.dburl=jdbc\:mysql\://192.168.1.209\:3306/applicarenew?allowPublicKeyRetrieval\=true&useSSL\=false
    applicare.smtp_auth_user=test
    applicare.custAlertClass=
    applicare.serverIP=192.168.1.209
    applicare.agentJobInterval=1
    applicare.dbTestSQL=SELECT 1
     applicare.smtp_from=
    applicare.enable_readonly_mode=false
    applicare.sendMailTo=test@localhost.com
    applicare.alertMonitorJobInterval=1
    applicare.alertOn=1
    applicare.intellitrace.auto_refresh=60000
    applicare.SMTPPort=25
    applicare.enable_server_time=false
    applicare.systemPassword=JFUuyKJT1Ls\=
    applicare.serverName=
    applicare.httpErrorCode=400
    applicare.monitorOn=1
    applicare.ipLocUpdate.jobInterval=60
    applicare.alertClearanceNotificationDuration=3
    applicare.logDir=/usr/local/Applicare/logs
    applicare.dataSource=Applicare-DataSource
    applicare.minTimeBetweenAlerts=5
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: applicare-config
  namespace: applicare

---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  namespace: applicare
  labels:
    run: applicare
  name: applicare
spec:
  replicas: 3
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      run: applicare
  template:
    metadata:
      annotations:
      labels:
        run: applicare
    spec:
      containers:
      - image: 'applicare:latest'
        imagePullPolicy: Never
        name: applicare
        resources:
          requests:
            memory: "2000Mi"
            cpu: "200m"
          limits:
            memory: "5000Mi"
            cpu: "2000m"
        volumeMounts:
        - name: app-config
          mountPath: /usr/local/Applicare/Applicare.props
          subPath: app.properties
        livenessProbe:
          httpGet:
            path: /applicare/login/console.jsp
            port: 8880
          failureThreshold: 5
          periodSeconds: 60
         #  terminationGracePeriodSeconds: 200
          initialDelaySeconds: 180
        startupProbe:
          httpGet:
            path: /applicare/login/console.jsp
            port: 8880
          failureThreshold: 3
          periodSeconds: 90
      volumes:
      - name: app-config
        configMap:
          name: applicare-config

---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  namespace: applicare
  name: applicare-service
spec:
  selector:
    run: applicare
  ports:
    - port: 8880
      targetPort: 8880
      name: port1
    - port: 8984
      targetPort: 8983
      name: port2

---

apiVersion: autoscaling/v2
kind: HorizontalPodAutoscaler
metadata:
  name: applicare
  namespace: applicare
spec:
  maxReplicas: 3
  minReplicas: 1
  scaleTargetRef:
    apiVersion: apps/v1
    kind: Deployment
    name: applicare
  metrics:
  - type: Resource
    resource:
      name: cpu
      target:
        type: Utilization
        averageUtilization: 80
  - type: Resource
    resource:
      name: memory
      target:
        type: Utilization
        averageUtilization: 97

---
apiVersion: policy/v1
kind: PodDisruptionBudget
metadata:
  name: applicare-pdb
  namespace: applicare
spec:
  minAvailable: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      run: applicare
```

After creating the pod (**kubectl describe pod -n applicare applicare-db4dcb7c7-6zzzw**) execute this command and i will get the following error. Is there any problem with yaml file or port opening problem?

```
Warning  Unhealthy  14m   kubelet            Startup probe failed: Get "http://10.1.0.82:8880/applicare/login/console.jsp": context deadline exceeded (Client.Timeout exceeded while awaiting headers)
```

Comment: Where's the image coming from since you set the pull policy to `never`? Is it responding correctly on port 8880/applicare/login/console.jsp ?

Comment: I pull the image from the local machine and i ran the kubernetes on that same machine

Comment: Ok so when you run the same image bare, does the app respond? eg `docker run -d --rm -p 8880:8880 applicare:latest` and then `curl -vvv -L -k localhost:8880` ?

Comment: After i execute that command

Comment: *   Trying 127.0.0.1:8880...
* Connected to localhost (127.0.0.1) port 8880 (#0)
> GET / HTTP/1.1
> Host: localhost:8880
> User-Agent: curl/8.1.2
> Accept: */*
> 
< HTTP/1.1 302 
< Set-Cookie: JSESSIONID=9D996A566F0457DAEA8688156AB9B590; Path=/; HttpOnly
< Location: /applicare
< vary: accept-encoding
< Content-Type: text/html;charset=ISO-8859-1
< Content-Length: 0
< Date: Fri, 11 Aug 2023 10:04:44 GMT

Comment: I able to connect that  container

Comment: Check the container logs for a failure signal

Comment: I don't see any failure or error message container logs.

Comment: This image access  well in docker but the same image running on kubernetes it didn't work.

Comment: The YAML seems fine (especially if `kubectl apply -f` accepted it) and there's not any particular port manipulation you need to do.  You'd need to understand why the URL in the error message (the pod IP plus the configured URL path) isn't responding (promptly).  That probably involves knowing something about the software running in the image.

Comment: In that pod tomcat is running on port 8880, I redirect the same 8880 port to 8880

Comment: Have you checked this [git link](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/89898#issuecomment-1028654403). does it help you to resolve your issue?.

Comment: given your other question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76883397/i-unable-to-inside-the-kubernetes-pod this seems a lot like your cluster overall has some issues rather than the single pod